# Grunt dynamic file mapping generates excessive paths

Tags: css, gruntjs, less

I am using the following:

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = function(grunt) {

  grunt.initConfig({
    less: {
      options: {
        paths: '/',
        yuicompress: false,
        ieCompat: true,
        compress: false,
        sourceMap: true,
        sourceMapFilename: 'alice/public/local/less/intfarm.css.map',
        require: [
          'alice/public/local/less/intfarm.less'
        ]
      },
      src: {
        expand: true,
        src: ['alice/public/local/less/*.less'],
        ext: '.css',
        dest: 'alice/public/local/css/local/compiled/',
      }
    },
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-less');
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['less']);
}
```

I don't understand why is the 'src' path generated also for the 'dest' path.. :

```
/alice/public/local/css/local/compiled/alice/public/local/less/account.css
```

I was expecting:

```
/alice/public/local/css/local/compiled/account.css
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're not using `cwd` option. `src` option contains [matching patterns](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#globbing-patterns) that resolves to paths relative to cwd path. Simply speaking, all file paths matched in `src` will be in the `dest` result.

So you need the following config to solve your problem.

```
src: {
    expand: true,
    cwd: 'alice/public/local/less/',
    src: ['*.less'],
    ext: '.css',
    dest: 'alice/public/local/css/local/compiled/',
  }
```

Comment: `flatten` helped in your case, this option just makes the results as flat tree. But it wouldn't help if someone wanted to preserve directory structure, e.g. `/header/logo.css`, etc.

Comment: that's the thing I didn't want to preserve the structure as source and destination had completely different paths.. (or am I wrong?)

Comment: Yeah, you could use whatever approach works for you :) I'm just tried to explain why it works.